# Porting bitfields from c++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net

I am porting a C++ library, which uses bitfields extensively into C# code.

Here is a an example of a bitfield class

```
struct Header{
  uint32_t A;
  uint16_t B: 1;
  uint16_t C: 1;
  uint16_t D: 1;
  uint16_t  : 13;
  uint16_t E;
};
```

When turning this class into a C# class should I keep bitfield information or just neglect the bitfield information.

```
classNoBitFieldHeader{
  uint A;
  bool B;
  bool C;
  bool D;
  ushort E;
};
```

or somewhere along the lines of

```
public class Header
{

    private readonly BitArray _bitArray = new BitArray(16);

    public uint A;

    public bool B
    {
        get => _bitArray.Get(0);
        set => _bitArray.Set(0,value);
    } 

    public bool C
    {
        get => _bitArray.Get(1);
        set => _bitArray.Set(1, value);
    }

    public bool D{
        get => _bitArray.Get(0);
        set => _bitArray.Set(0,value);
    }

    public ushort E;
}
```

In the latter I am happy that I kept all the information available but I am not sure if it should be kept at all

Comment: It depends on how it uses them. Is it just in-memory or is the data written/read from files directly and that’s why the bits are kept that way? Is it just memory optimization? Is it just preference?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, Thanks for the comment, there are some serialization / deserialization. Writing and reading the files but since, this is a complete rewrite, I will also handle those serialization cases as well. From my point of view current uses of bitfield is as a memory optimization. To be more precise, this is a library of a game series that is going on about for 30 years. So I think they needed to optimize every single bit in the past but not any more

Comment: In that case I’d probably go for using bools and handling (de)serializing manually for them to make it easier. Then see if there’s any issues and go from there. Also using raw bit arithmetic might be faster than BitArray if there’s need for actual bit fields.